# Python - is an object the same after it is passed into constructor?

Tags: python

Maybe the question is not clear. I can show an example.

```
class foo:
     def __init__(self):
          pass

     var1 = ''

     def set_var1(self, value):
          self.var1 = value

class bar:
     def __init__(self, foo):
          self.my_foo = foo

     my_foo = None

     def call_var1(self):
          print('var1:'+ foo(self.my_foo).var1)
```

in main.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     my_foo = foo()
     my_foo.set_var1 = 'Hello'
     my_bar = bar(my_foo)
     my_bar.call_var1()
```

And after I call the method `call_var1()`, I get a result: `"var1:"`. It seems the value is not assigned to the object my_foo inside of bar? Is that a special feature of python?

Comment: The only result _I_ get from that piece of code is an exception. You may want to post code that actually works...

Comment: I can't get your code to run: `foo(self.my_foo)` results in `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Comment: your code is not working and your question is not very explained, what are u trying to archive?

Comment: @quamrana your result gives me a little hint. The reason why I add foo before self.my_foo is the program does not know the type of my_foo, so it cannot call the variable var1. I add the foo() to tell the system, this is a foo type object. However, from your result, foo() is creating a new object....... That could be the point.

Comment: Python is not a strongly typed language. `foo(self.my_foo)` is not declaring or converting `self.my_foo` as a `foo` type but instead it's attempting to create a new instance of `foo` by, ultimately, calling its _constructor_  `__init__()` and passing the `self.my_foo` as its first argument.

Comment: It is true that the program does not know the type of `self.my_foo`, but you only need to call `self.my_foo.var1` as @Ollie has indicated, because python does a look-up at runtime.

Comment: @quamrana ok, I get it. I am using IDE to program. So when the IDE doesn't pop the function names to me doesn't mean the program will crush during the runtime, right?

Comment: That's right. You can only know these things at runtime with python. So you need to run your programs early and often. Using TDD helps here.

Comment: @quamrana hahaha, I am applying TDD actually. Thanks for help. Do you mind to answer my question again and I mark your word as answer?

Comment: @JiekeWei Actually I think you should mark Ollie's answer as accepted and upvote as well.

Comment: @quamrana fine. but I think you really answered my question\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: **yes**. An object is the same after it is passed into a constructor.

I made two fixes:

1. Removed the `foo()` around `self.my_foo` in `bar`'s `call_var1(self)` function.
2. Changed `my_foo.set_var1 = 'Hello'` to `my_foo.set_var1('Hello')`.

Resulting code:

```
 class foo:
      def __init__(self):
           pass

      var1 = ''

      def set_var1(self, value):
           self.var1 = value

 class bar:
      def __init__(self, foo):
           self.my_foo = foo

      my_foo = None

      def call_var1(self):
           print('var1:'+ self.my_foo.var1)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
      my_foo = foo()
      my_foo.set_var1('Hello')
      my_bar = bar(my_foo)
      my_bar.call_var1()
```

The output is now:

```
var1:Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

I still not understand what you are trying to do but I think in this way your code is a bit more understandable:

```
class foo:
     def __init__(self, value):
         self.var1 = value

class bar:
     def __init__(self, foo):
          self.my_foo = foo

     def call_var1(self):
          print('var1:'+ self.my_foo.var1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     my_foo = foo('Hello')
     my_bar = bar(my_foo)
     my_bar.call_var1()
```

In any case u are assigned your foo object to your self.my_foo but logically not the value of the variable. if you want assign to your variable self.my_foo the value of self.var1 you have to do:

```
class foo:
     def __init__(self, value):
          self.var1 = value

class bar:
     def __init__(self, foo):
          self.my_foo = foo.var1

     def call_var1(self):
          print('var1:'+ self.my_foo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     my_foo = foo('Hello')
     my_bar = bar(my_foo)
     my_bar.call_var1()
```